# Firebase functions gen2 python init does not work

Tags: python, function, google-cloud-platform

I have only one python installed in my system: `3.10.10`. it includes the latest pip: `23.1.2` and I installed the latest module of `firebase_functions`

After I try to init firebase functions in my machine I follow the instructions and when it asks me to install dependencies I get this error:

```
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
C:\Users\XXX\functions\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Next time I run the same process but this time I did not accept to install dependencies and it worked:

```
 Firebase initialization complete!
```

Now this is the default code google provided:

```
# Welcome to Cloud Functions for Firebase for Python!
# To get started, simply uncomment the below code or create your own.
# Deploy with `firebase deploy`

from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

initialize_app()


@https_fn.on_request()
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

I have all dependencies installed. I made sure thousand times.
When I run

```
firebase deploy
```

I get this error:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

 Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

And this is the log in the firebase-debug.log

```
[debug] [2023-06-11T13:05:29.172Z] stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_functions'

[debug] [2023-06-11T13:05:29.182Z] Error: spawn "C:\Users\XXX\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
at cp.emit (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently firebase creates its own python dependency separately from your own python version in your machine. It is stored in the `venv` folder.
To make it work follow the following steps:

```
firebase init
```

Choose functions: `Functions: Configure a Cloud Functions directory and its files`

When it asks: `Do you want to install dependencies now? (Y/n)`

Choose `No`

Open **cmd** within the functions project and then:

```
cd functions\venv\Scripts
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
python.exe -m pip install firebase_functions
cd ../../../
```

And now:

```
firebase init functions
```

Choose Overwrite, and then:

```
File functions/requirements.txt already exists. Overwrite? No
File functions/.gitignore already exists. Overwrite? No
File functions/main.py already exists. Overwrite? No
Do you want to install dependencies now? Yes
```

And now:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

And it should work perfectly

Comment: I see this selected as the answer but it's not resolving this issue for me. Should you have the venv activated when you deploy?

Comment: thank you so much ! This works for me.
But i skipped this : firebase init functions
i just started the emulator after installing the dependencies.
firebase emulators:start --only functions